# What does the 5th position of os.times return value mean exactly?

Tags: python

I understand that the python `os.times()` function will return a 5 position tuple, the first four positions being (I think) different processor time measurements.

However, there is one thing about this function that confuse me.  What is the 5th position?  Time elapsed since a fixed point in the past?  Since which point?  Is this for measuring wall-clock time?  Is that what the documentation means when it says "(processor or other) times"?

Comment: Have you read the other documents [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.times) refers to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* times are relative to a fixed point; it is up to the OS to pick that point, and that varies even between versions of the same OS.

See the [`man times(2)` documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times):

> On Linux, the "arbitrary point in the past" from which the return value of `times()` is measured has varied across kernel versions. On Linux 2.4 and earlier this point is the moment the system was booted. Since Linux 2.6, this point is (2^32/HZ) - 300 (i.e., about 429 million) seconds before system boot time. This variability across kernel versions (and across UNIX implementations), combined with the fact that the returned value may overflow the range of `clock_t`, means that a portable application would be wise to avoid using this value. To measure changes in elapsed time, use `clock_gettime(2)` instead.

Python returns you the `tms_utime`, `tms_stime`, `tms_cutime`, `tms_cstime` fields from the `clock_t` struct, with the 5th value being the return value of the `times()` call itself, so *the number of clock ticks that have elapsed since an arbitrary point in the past*. It has already translated these values from clock ticks to a floating point value representing seconds.

That fifth value then just tells you how far in the past, in seconds, that arbitrary point lies, in wall-clock time (or as close to that as possible as measured by the OS).